# How to change JSON file to be readable?

Tags: json

I've created a `JSON`.
This `JSON` file will be a source of query in ElasticSearch

This query works in ElasticSearch and returns results.
When I store the query to `JSON`, I see that JSON is valid. But when I read it from `JSON` I have an error.
It's my JSON:

```
{
  "function_score": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "query_string": {
              "default_field": "headline",
              "query": "engineer"
            }
          },
          {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "functions": [
      {
        "script_score": {
          "script": {
            "params": {
              "queryVector": [1,2,5],
              "max_score": "max_score"
            },
            "source": "if (_score>0 && params.max_score>0){return  doc['embedding_headline'].size() == 0 ? 0 : Math.min(Math.max(_score/params.max_score,cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, 'embedding_headline')),1) + 1.0} else { return doc['embedding_headline'].size() == 0 ? 0 : cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, 'embedding_headline') + 1.0}",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "score_mode": "max",
    "boost_mode": "replace",
  }
}
```

I use python for reading `JSON`.
It's code for reading:

```
import json

file_path = 'queries.json'

with open(file_path) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

It's error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 34 column 5 (char 1012)
```

What should I change in this `JSON` to make it readable?

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using? what code have you tried so far?

Comment: @Serge thanks, added this info above

Answer (score 0):

That json is invalid.
I just pasted it into a json validator and it has errors in it.

CHeck this link:

[json lint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Paste your json there, it throws the following errors:

```
Error: Parse error on line 30:
..._mode": "replace",   }}
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got '}'
```

If you are using python it often throws errors due to string quotation as well.
Try to enclose the script source field in single quotes instead of doubles. That could be another problem.

Last but not the least, function score queries are extremely slow, and I would recommend not using them!